# Live help call service - need to position available live helpers automatically at the top of the list when they are logged in to receive calls

Tags: positioning

I am trying to figure out how to code a list of advisors that use live call buttons.  Right now, I have a static list of advisors and their individual call buttons state "Available" or "Unavailable" according to whether or not they are signed in as ready to take live calls.  I want to code the list of advisors so that those that are logged in as Available automatically move to the top of the Advisor List.  I do not want my site visitors to have to scroll through all the Advisors to see who is Available and who is not.  I want those that are ready to take calls to automatically populate to the top.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a lot of information to help here, but if you are pulling from a database, you would do so like this:

```
SELECT advisor
FROM advisor_table
ORDER BY Status
```

You may need to reverse the `ORDER BY` clause if that puts the unavailable ones on top.